# MvvmCross MvxListView and MvxItemTemplate. How do I get a table to display correctly?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to create a data entry table using MvvmCross.  Here is what I have:

ShipmentView.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/InputEditText"
        local:MvxBind="Text Shipment.Shipper" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/InputEditText"
        local:MvxBind="Text Shipment.OrgAddress" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/InputEditText"
        local:MvxBind="Text Shipment.OrgEmail" />
    <Mvx.MvxListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource ShipmentInventory.Items"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/inventoryitemdetailview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

ShipmentInventory.Items is an ObservableCollection of ShipmentInventoryItem.  The template for my items is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <EditText
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/InputEditText"
      local:MvxBind="Text TagColor" />
  <EditText
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/InputEditText"
      local:MvxBind="Text TagLot" />
  <EditText
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/InputEditText"
      local:MvxBind="Text Articles" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Code for my ViewModel is:

```
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using MPS_Mobile_Driver.Droid.DataModel;
using MPSDataService;
using System;

namespace MPS_Mobile_Driver.Droid.ViewModels
{
    public class ShipmentViewModel
      : MvxViewModel
    {
        public async void Init(int idno, short idsub)
        {
            Shipment = await MPS_Mobile_Driver.Droid.DataModel.ShipmentDataSource.GetShipment(idno, idsub);
            await MPS_Mobile_Driver.Droid.DataModel.ShipmentDataSource.GetShipmentInventory (Guid.Parse("59361EA3-C688-41FB-AF96-DF50F357272B"));
            ShipmentInventory = ShipmentDataSource.CurrInventory;
        }

        private Shipment _Shipment;
        public Shipment Shipment
        {
            get { return _Shipment; }
            set { _Shipment = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Shipment); }
        }
        private ShipmentInventory _ShipmentInventory;
        public ShipmentInventory ShipmentInventory
        {
            get { return _ShipmentInventory; }
            set { _ShipmentInventory = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => ShipmentInventory); }
        }
    }
}
```

This is all working except the details in the MvxListView are jacked up.  It shows the value for the first column as the whole line and the other two columns as blank lines after that then rinse and repeat times about 30 items.  My theme template just makes it white background with black letters. It is as follows just in case it is the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="InputEditText" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/black_cursor</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Maybe I shouldn't use a linear layout.  I do want the table to have columns across the screen.  I am very new to Android programming so I am sure it is some tiny detail that I missed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jim

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Could you possible add a sketch diagram to show what "jacked up" means? (Sorry feeling dim and the google results for "jacked up" were decidedly nsfw!)

Comment: Perhaps a better phrase would be "not as expected"  Sorry for the vernacular.  I will figure a way to show what it looks like.

Comment: @Stuart I added a screen shot of the screen to my original post.  Please see what you think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was actually a really easy fix as the problem was with me being a noob to Android.  All I had to do was put a fixed width on the EditTexts...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <EditText
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/InputEditText"
      local:MvxBind="Text TagColor" />
  <EditText
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/InputEditText"
      local:MvxBind="Text TagLot" />
  <EditText
      android:layout_width="300dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/InputEditText"
      local:MvxBind="Text Articles" />
</LinearLayout>
```

@Stuart thanks for looking at this.  In the future I will have to google my slang before I use it in a post.  It meant what I thought it meant, but it had a lot of other meanings as well O.o

Cheers,
Jim

Comment: If it helps - the hierarchy viewer is a great tool in Android!

Comment: @Stuart, is it part of the Xamarin Visual Studio plungin?  That is what I am using.

Comment: Get in touch with your Android - http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html

Comment: @Stuart the hierarchy viewer is a huge help.  Thanks!